# What does `clean, x/y` mean in fsck output?

Tags: filesystems, fsck

When I run `fsck`, I see output like:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/sda1: clean, 3811/49152 files, 105570/171776 blocks
```

Which I understand means everything is okay (because there are no errors),
but what does `3811/49152 files` and `105570/171776 blocks` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which I understand means everything is okay (because there are no errors),
>   but what does 3811/49152 files and 105570/171776 blocks mean?

This means that the checked file system uses 3811 inodes (usually you need (at least) one inode per file) out of 49152 inodes available.

The same to the blocks: 105570 out of 171776 blocks are currently in use. If not specified otherwise the default block size in Linux ext2, ext3, ext4 file systems is 1 KByte (1024 bytes).

Comment: This is along the lines of what I first thought, but `df -i` and `df` reveal 443/239944 inodes and 0/959776 blocks. [Why the disparity?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185482)

Comment: Ahh, `df` only works on mounted partitions, so [`df /dev/sda1` returns filesystem data for the in-memory filesystem `dev`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185488/38514).